# How do I add a box-shadow property to scrollbar-track？

Tags: css

This is a simple demo  => [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-violet-ilvg6l?file=/index.html)

The odd thing is that scrollbar-track seems to be able to add any attribute except box-shadow,
Unless I add the 'inset' property, but I don't want the 'inset' effect.

This is the style code

```
    .scroll-box {
      height: 300px;
      overflow: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 10px;
     }
    .scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border-radius: 10px;
      background-color: #7d7d7d;
      border: 2px solid transparent;
      background-clip: content-box;
     }
    .scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      border: 1px solid red;
      box-shadow: -4px 0 20px #000;
    }
```

This is html code

```
    <div class="scroll-box">
      .............omit
    </div>
```

[Expect normal shading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fg5j.png)
What should I do?

Comment: Well I am seeing the box - shadow applied in the demo you have shared. is this something particular you are looking to implement?

Comment: yep, I want to create a shadow effect on the left side of the scroll bar

Comment: can you please let us know which browser you are using? In chrome I am able to see the shadow appearing in left side of the scroll bar.

Comment: Really? I use chrome  too. but I can't see the left shadow in my project or in codesandbox.

Comment: Yes, I am using the chrome v110.0.5481.77. I have just changed the box-shadow color to blue.  Image for reference

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm4S6.png

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I think I understand a little bit. Is it the operating system? Is your operating system windows?

Comment: I don't think its becoz of OS. I am as well using windows 11 OS.

Comment: Sorry, there may be some grammatical problems in my last sentence, and my English is no good.   I want to express is that I use macOS, so we can see different effects.   If the reason is that OS, is there any way you can get it to display properly on macOS as well.

Comment: Well, I checked in macOs right now. I am seeing some strange behavior with the code sandbox in chrome of macOS.  I can see the box shadow when I increase the width of the preview window. Please see the screenshot for reference:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiR3C.jpg

Comment: yes, I also tried it, and when the view width was enough to keep the content from scrolling, the shadow effect came out.I don't understand how this works